# Neo4j Cypher - merge columns and get distinct values from all

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I've got a complex query that I'm trying to do with `OPTIONAL MATCH` statements.  It looks like this:

```
MATCH (p:Person {name:'Victoria'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:MANAGES]->(:Office)<-[MERGES_INTO*0..]-(:Office)<-[:WORKS_WITH]-(target1) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:SUPPORTS]->(:Office)<-[MERGES_INTO*0..]-(:Office)<-[:WORKS_WITH]-(target2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:ASSISTS]->(:Person)-[*0..1]->(:Group)<--(target3)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-->(:Group)<--(target4)
RETURN DISTINCT target1,target2,target3,target4
```

What I want to do is get the results as if they were a single column called `target` instead of getting `target1`, `target2`, `target3`, and `target4` back as separate columns.

Is there a way to collect/unwind the four potential target columns to return them as a single column result set?

I know I could get the desired result using a `UNION` of four separate queries that return a value called target, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, and you're on the right track. Here's an example using collect and unwind to do this:

```
MATCH (p:Person {name:'Victoria'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:MANAGES]->(:Office)<-[:MERGES_INTO*0..]-(:Office)<-[:WORKS_WITH]-(target1) 
WITH p, COLLECT(target1) as target1s
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:SUPPORTS]->(:Office)<-[:MERGES_INTO*0..]-(:Office)<-[:WORKS_WITH]-(target2)
WITH p, target1s, COLLECT(target2) as target2s
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:ASSISTS]->(:Person)-[*0..1]->(:Group)<--(target3)
WITH p, target1s, target2s, COLLECT(target3) as target3s
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-->(:Group)<--(target4)
WITH target1s + target2s + target3s + COLLECT(target4) AS targets
UNWIND targets AS target
RETURN DISTINCT target
```

Note that you should be able to collapse the :MANAGES and :SUPPORTS optional matches into a single [:MANAGES|SUPPORTS] relationship, as the rest of the path is the same.

Comment: That is exactly the example I needed to get a handle on `collect` and `with`. Thanks very much.